# JavaScript verificar links quebrados

Tags: javascript

É possível verificar links quebrados em um arquivo html usando javascript e caso esteja quebrado sinalizar com cor diferente, ou então sinalizar os links que não estão quebrados com uma cor específica como quando são visitados?

Tenho este script que lista os links de uma página, talvez pode ser implementado a verificação nele.

```
javascript: var w = window.open('', '', 'height=300, width=300');
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var b = a.length; 

if(b != 0){ 
  w.document.write('<h1> Lista de Links </h1> '); 

  for (i = 0; i < b; i++){ 
    w.document.write('<pre><a href=\'' + a[i] + '\'>' + a[i] + '</a>' + '</pre> ');
  }

} else{ 
    w.document.write('Nenhum link encontrado');
}
```

Comment: Teria que fazer requisições, e verificar o *Status*. Relacionado: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591401

Comment: Os links são do mesmo domínio?

Comment: @dvd sim, são do mesmo domínio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Conforme informado pelo AP, os links são do mesmo domínio, logo não há
>   problemas com CORS.

Use o `XMLHttpRequest()` percorrendo cada tag `<a>`. Como o Ajax faz uma requisição, no código abaixo eu coloquei um tempo de 1 segundo para cada consulta, mas você aumentar ou diminuir (ou mesmo retirar o `setTimeout`). As explicações estão todas no código:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ // verifica se o DOM foi carregado
   var links = document.body.querySelectorAll("a"); // seleciona todas as tags <a>
   var nums_links = links.length; // conta a quantidade
   var conta = 0; // contador

   function checaLinks(){
      var url_ = links[conta].href; // seta o href do link como a URL ser consultada
      var http = new XMLHttpRequest(); // cria o objeto XHR
      http.open("GET", url_, true); // consulta o link
      http.onreadystatechange = function(){ // retorno do Ajax
         if(http.readyState == 4){ // retorno completado
            if(http.status != 200){ // se for diferente de 200, é porque a URL não existe (cód. HTTP 404)
               links[conta].style.color = "red"; // muda a cor do link
            }

            if(conta < nums_links-1){ // verifica se o contador ainda está dentro do range do número de links
               setTimeout(checaLinks, 1000); // chama novamente a função após 1 segundo
            }
            conta++; // incrementa o contador
         }
      }
      http.send(null);
   }

   checaLinks();  // chama a função
});
```

Comment: Caraca @dvd! ficou muito show, muito massa ver os links ficando vermelhos a medida que iam sendo feitas requisições um a um, ;)
Tem algum limite de tempo mínimo pra não dar erro?

Comment: bota 100 no lugar de 1000

Comment: Massa, vlw mesmo!

Comment: veja se não está tendo problema com o CORS com esse código... estava fazendo um faz um tempo e está dando erro aqui semelhante a este... tente com um link válido e veja se ele continua na cor original.

Comment: @Dudaskank Os links são do mesmo domínio.

Comment: Não tinha reparado no comentário do op ali em cima... mas já que pesquisei tanto coloquei minha resposta também rs. A propósito, por que você está esperando para fazer as requisições ajax, ao invés de fazer um loop no vetor de links e disparar uma nova requisição?

Comment: @Dudaskank rs... O que vc diz com "esperar"?

Comment: Esperar com o `setTimeout` ali. É que eu queria entender se é só uma opção sua mesmo para disparar as requisições mais lentamente, ao invés de todas rapidamente, ou se é alguma boa prática dar esse tempo entre elas mesmo.

Comment: @Dudaskank Entendi. Cara, não acho uma boa enviar 300 requisições ao servidor ao mesmo tempo. Se não der problema, tudo bem. Foi só uma sugestão, até coloquei que ele pode inclusive retirar o setTimeout se quiser.

Comment: @MiguelSilva E ai?! Blz? Vi que desmarcou a resposta. A outra resposta é melhor?

Comment: Não desmarquei, vi aqui, só pode marcar uma é?

Comment: Sim, apenas 1. Votar você pode votar em qualquer uma ou várias que quiser, mas marcar é apenas uma.

Comment: É que no seu script ainda que com mesmo domínio, é sinalizado como ok, por exemplo, 
 bibliaonline.com.br/acf/jo/3/16 dá ok, mas se for um link como este 
 bibliaonline.com.br/acf/jo/3/99 (inexistente) também dá ok.

Comment: @MiguelSilva Sim, eu testei aqui e funcionou normal.

Comment: Com estes dois links que te passei?

Comment: @MiguelSilva Não com esses links porque não estão no meu domínio. Eu testei no meu domínio uma pasta que não existe e funcionou normal.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79543/discussion-between-miguel-silva-and-dvd).

Answer (score 3):

Boa noite !

Você pode requisitar o link do site em questão e verificar o seu retorno

Exemplo..

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.seusite.com",
    type: "HEAD"
}).done(function() { 
    alert('Site existe!');
}).fail(function() { 
    alert('Site não existe!');
})
```

De acordo com o retorno da requisição, você descobre se está On ou Off

Espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: acredito que é por aí, vou adicionar, no meu post, um script que tenho que lista os links de uma página, então talvez possa ser complementado com este.

Answer (score 1):

Caso os links não sejam para o mesmo domínio, você terá problemas com a solução do @dvd ali, devido ao [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Controle_Acesso_CORS). Nesse caso, só com javascript você não vai conseguir. Precisará de um proxy no meio do caminho. Encontrei um que praticamente atende no github chamado [php-cross-domain-proxy](https://github.com/softius/php-cross-domain-proxy), só precisou de algumas modificações, que vou colocar aqui.

Copie os dois arquivos para o servidor, aqui usei o XAMPP na pasta `<XAMPP>\htdocs\testes`. Esse meu adiciona uma classe aos links quebrados e outra aos links ok para modificar o background deles após clicar no botão de verificar links.

## proxy.php

```
<?php

/**
 * AJAX Cross Domain (PHP) Proxy 0.8
 * Copyright (C) 2016 Iacovos Constantinou (https://github.com/softius)
 *
 * This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

/**
 * Enables or disables filtering for cross domain requests.
 * Recommended value: true
 */
define('CSAJAX_FILTERS', false);

/**
 * If set to true, $valid_requests should hold only domains i.e. a.example.com, b.example.com, usethisdomain.com
 * If set to false, $valid_requests should hold the whole URL ( without the parameters ) i.e. http://example.com/this/is/long/url/
 * Recommended value: false (for security reasons - do not forget that anyone can access your proxy)
 */
define('CSAJAX_FILTER_DOMAIN', false);

/**
 * Set debugging to true to receive additional messages - really helpful on development
 */
define('CSAJAX_DEBUG', true);

/**
 * A set of valid cross domain requests
 */
$valid_requests = array(
    // 'example.com'
);

/**
 * Set extra multiple options for cURL
 * Could be used to define CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER & CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST for HTTPS
 * Also to overwrite any other options without changing the code
 * See http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt-array.php
 */
$curl_options = array(
    // CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    // CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    //// parece não ser seguro isso, mas é mais prático ;)
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
);

/* * * STOP EDITING HERE UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING * * */

// identify request headers
$request_headers = array( );
foreach ($_SERVER as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'HTTP_') === 0  ||  strpos($key, 'CONTENT_') === 0) {
        $headername = str_replace('_', ' ', str_replace('HTTP_', '', $key));
        $headername = str_replace(' ', '-', ucwords(strtolower($headername)));
        if (!in_array($headername, array( 'Host', 'X-Proxy-Url' ))) {
            $request_headers[] = "$headername: $value";
        }
    }
}

// identify request method, url and params
$request_method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
if ('GET' == $request_method) {
    $request_params = $_GET;
} elseif ('POST' == $request_method) {
    $request_params = $_POST;
    if (empty($request_params)) {
        $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
        if (!empty($data)) {
            $request_params = $data;
        }
    }
} elseif ('PUT' == $request_method || 'DELETE' == $request_method) {
    $request_params = file_get_contents('php://input');
} else {
    $request_params = null;
}

// Get URL from `csurl` in GET or POST data, before falling back to X-Proxy-URL header.
if (isset($_REQUEST['csurl'])) {
    $request_url = urldecode($_REQUEST['csurl']);
} elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_PROXY_URL'])) {
    $request_url = urldecode($_SERVER['HTTP_X_PROXY_URL']);
} else {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');
    header('Status: 404 Not Found');
    $_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS'] = 404;
    exit;
}

$p_request_url = parse_url($request_url);

// csurl may exist in GET request methods
if (is_array($request_params) && array_key_exists('csurl', $request_params)) {
    unset($request_params['csurl']);
}

// ignore requests for proxy :)
if (preg_match('!' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . '!', $request_url) || empty($request_url) || count($p_request_url) == 1) {
    csajax_debug_message('Invalid request - make sure that csurl variable is not empty');
    exit;
}

// check against valid requests
if (CSAJAX_FILTERS) {
    $parsed = $p_request_url;
    if (CSAJAX_FILTER_DOMAIN) {
        if (!in_array($parsed['host'], $valid_requests)) {
            csajax_debug_message('Invalid domain - ' . $parsed['host'] . ' does not included in valid requests');
            exit;
        }
    } else {
        $check_url = isset($parsed['scheme']) ? $parsed['scheme'] . '://' : '';
        $check_url .= isset($parsed['user']) ? $parsed['user'] . ($parsed['pass'] ? ':' . $parsed['pass'] : '') . '@' : '';
        $check_url .= isset($parsed['host']) ? $parsed['host'] : '';
        $check_url .= isset($parsed['port']) ? ':' . $parsed['port'] : '';
        $check_url .= isset($parsed['path']) ? $parsed['path'] : '';
        if (!in_array($check_url, $valid_requests)) {
            csajax_debug_message('Invalid domain - ' . $request_url . ' does not included in valid requests');
            exit;
        }
    }
}

// append query string for GET requests
if ($request_method == 'GET' && count($request_params) > 0 && (!array_key_exists('query', $p_request_url) || empty($p_request_url['query']))) {
    $request_url .= '?' . http_build_query($request_params);
}

// let the request begin
$ch = curl_init($request_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers);   // (re-)send headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);     // return response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);       // enabled response headers
// add data for POST, PUT or DELETE requests
if ('POST' == $request_method) {
    $post_data = is_array($request_params) ? http_build_query($request_params) : $request_params;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $post_data);
} elseif ('PUT' == $request_method || 'DELETE' == $request_method) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $request_method);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_params);
}

// Set multiple options for curl according to configuration
if (is_array($curl_options) && 0 <= count($curl_options)) {
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_options);
}

// retrieve response (headers and content)
$response = curl_exec($ch);
// dava erro quando tinha problema no curl
if ($response === false) {
  header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');
  header('Status: 404 Not Found');
  $_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS'] = 404;
  csajax_debug_message('error: ' . curl_error($ch));
  curl_close($ch);
  exit;
}
curl_close($ch);

// split response to header and content
list($response_headers, $response_content) = preg_split('/(\r\n){2}/', $response, 2);

// (re-)send the headers
$response_headers = preg_split('/(\r\n){1}/', $response_headers);
foreach ($response_headers as $key => $response_header) {
    // Rewrite the `Location` header, so clients will also use the proxy for redirects.
    if (preg_match('/^Location:/', $response_header)) {
        list($header, $value) = preg_split('/: /', $response_header, 2);
        $response_header = 'Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '?csurl=' . $value;
    }
    if (!preg_match('/^(Transfer-Encoding):/', $response_header)) {
        header($response_header, false);
    }
}

// finally, output the content
print($response_content);

function csajax_debug_message($message)
{
    if (true == CSAJAX_DEBUG) {
        print $message . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

## checar-links.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Checagem de links</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.3/animate.min.css'>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>

  <style>
  .link-ok {
    background: #afa;
  }
  .link-quebrado {
    background: #faa;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='jumbotron text-center'>
      <h1>Checagem de links <i class="fa fa-link"></i></h1>
      <p>Verificando quais links da página estão quebrados ou não.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- jumbotron -->
    <p>Aqui no codepen não consigo fazer nenhum GET, então está ficando tudo vermelho :P.</p>
    <p><button id="verificar" class="btn btn-default">Verificar Links</button></p>
    <p>
      <ul>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://codepen.io/dudaskank">https://codepen.io/dudaskank</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://codepen.io/werueowruoiuweiuwoieuroiweuoirweuoiruweoiuroiweuroiewu">https://codepen.io/werueowruoiuweiuwoieuroiweuoirweuoiruweoiuroiweuroiewu</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com">https://www.google.com</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.googlex.com">https://www.googlex.com (não existe, da erro no curl e o proxy manda um 404)</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.globo.com">https://www.globo.com</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="http://dudaskank.com">http://dudaskank.com</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="http://localhost/testes/nao-existe.html">http://localhost/testes/nao-existe.html</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="http://localhost/testes/checar-links.html">http://localhost/testes/checar-links.html</a>(sou eu mesmo)</li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="checar-links.html">checar-links.html</a>(sou eu mesmo de novo, só pra mostrar que funciona com caminhos relativos)</li>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="/testes/checar-links.html">/testes/checar-links.html</a>(outra vez)</li>
      </ul>
    </p>

  </div>
  <!-- content -->
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'></script>

  <script>
  var botao = document.getElementById("verificar");
  botao.addEventListener("click", verificarTodosLinks, false);

  function verificarTodosLinks() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(links, function(link) {    
      verificarLink(link);
    });
    console.log(links);
  }

  function verificarLink(el) {
    var url = el.href;
    // https://gist.github.com/rafaelstz/5a4aa3584061131d714b709ba773c5f8
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Cria um evento para receber o retorno.
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
      // Caso o state seja 4 e o http.status for 200, é porque a requisiçõe deu certo.
      console.log("link, status: ", url, ajax.status);
      if (ajax.readyState == 4) {
        if (ajax.status == 200) {
          var data = ajax.responseText;
          el.className += " link-ok";
          // Retorno do Ajax
          console.log(data);
        } else {
          el.className += " link-quebrado";
        }
      }
    };
    // Seta tipo de requisição e URL com os parâmetros
    ajax.open("GET", "proxy.php?csurl=" + url, true);
    // Envia a requisição
    ajax.send();
  }
  </script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ficou Muito show o layout, como adiciono uma index.html, assim bastaria adicionar a página na pasta testes, por exempo, com nome index.html e já teria o conteúdo carregado, no layout, acho que seria legal

Comment: Após alguns testes com pagina que possui muitos links, vários links válidos foram dados como inválidos

Comment: No caso do index.html, só renomear o arquivo para index.html mesmo que tudo OK. Sobre o erro em página com vários links, se for algo constante pode ser um erro mesmo, mas por aqui não tive problemas, se for eventual pode ser algum problema de conexão temporário que você passou.

Comment: onde adicionar esta linha pra fazer requisições com tempo determinado: setTimeout(checaLinks, 1000);

Comment: Você quer  verificar todos os links após um certo tempo? Pode fazer isso direto após o carregamento da página também, mas para esperar um tempo, coloque no final do `<script>` assim: `setTimeout(verificarTodosLinks, 1000); // chama a função daqui 1 segundo`

Comment: Certo Obrigado, vlw